# How to Disable ImeAction/Button on the Soft Keyboard when TextField is Empty

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have this TextFied Composable with both `KeyboardOptions` and `KeyboardActions`.

```
@Composable
fun TodoInputText(...) {
    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    TextField( ....
        onValueChange = onTextChanged,
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = {
            onImeAction()
            keyboardController?.hide()
        }))}
```

The TextField is working with the Done Action but I need to disable Done ImeAction on the keyboard whenever the TextFied is empty as illustrated on this GIF

[image]

I have already extracted a state to check if the TextField is empty.

```
@Composable
fun TodoItemEntryInput(...) {

    //hold state for TextField
    val (text, setText) = remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    val isTextBlank = text.isNotBlank()

    //declare lambda function submit that handles  a submit event when done is pressed
    val submitAction = { .... }

    TodoItemInput(
        text = text,
        onTextChange = setText,
        submitAction = submitAction,
       
    )}
```

Now my question is how can I use the `isTextBlank` state to disable or Gray-out the Done ImeAction whenever the text is empty. This is to avoid bugs if the user enters blank text - I found input verification not very optimal for this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10564062/3585796) in regular Android, so with Jetpack Compose this task also cannot be solved.

All you can do is check if the text in the `onDone` callback is valid, continue if it is, and show an error if it is not.

Comment: Thanks very much @Philip Dukhov for this info, saved my day. Just for my info is there any way to highlight such situations with Google's Android Team?

Comment: @Tonnie sure, you can create an issue on [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128)

Comment: Awesome, I am on it.

Answer (score 1):

you can set IME action on text change of edit text

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.length() > 0) {
               editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
            } else {
               editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NONE);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm setting the `imeAction` to `None` if the value is not valid and to `Done/Go` if it is.
Then plug the value into the `keyboardOptions` in the `TextField`

```
// setup the value
val imeAction = if (isValidInput(seekerInfoUiState.value)) {
    ImeAction.Done // or ImeAction.Go
} else {
    ImeAction.None
}

// plug the value and handle the action
TextField(
   keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
    imeAction = imeAction,
   ),
   keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
     onDone = { // or onGo
        /* do something when imeAction is clicked */
     }

   )
)
```

All the best...